# Getting parsing error when attempting to remove empty xml tags with lxml

Tags: python, csv, parsing, lxml

I'm in the process of creating an xml file from a csv source, and have had some very useful input from users in this process. It appears that my last requirement (of which I've only just become aware), is to drop any empty xml tags (that is, those with no content) before calling an API.

I'm attempting to use the etree remove method to drop the empty tags, but I'm getting an error that etree.fromstring can only parse strings.  Here is my sample data and code.

```
ACTION|INV_ACCT_CLASS|EXT_INV_ID|WAREHOUSE_ID|NAME|CNTRY_CD|PHONE|ADDR_STR1|ADDR_STR2|CITY|ST|ZIP|ADD_KEY_NUM
add|2|AAA_00005|1001213|Company 1|US|9995555555|1313 Mockingbird Lane||New York|NY|10001|44433322
add|2|BBB_00008|1004312|Company 2|US|43255511110|Some other address||Stamford|CT|44112|11122233
```

```
import lxml.etree
 from lxml.builder import E 
 import csv
 import string
 import date from datetime

with open("filename.csv") as csvfile:

                    
  results = E.paiInv(*(
              E.invrec(
               E.action(row['ACTION']),
                E.investor(
                E.inv_account_class(row['INV_ACCOUNT_CLASS']),
                E.ext_inv_id(row['EXT_INV_ID']),
                E.warehouse_id(row['WAREHOUSE_ID']),
                E.name(row['NAME']),
                E.cntry_cd(row['CNTRY_CD']),
                E.phone(row['PHONE']),
                E.addr_str1(row['ADDRESS_STR1']),
                E.addr_str2(row['ADDRESS_STR2']),
                E.city(row['CITY']),
                E.st(row['ST']),
                E.zip(row['ZIP']),
                E.add_key_num(row['ADD_KEY_NUM'])
                      )
                ) for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = '|'))
                          )

  req = '<request_id>Investor' + str(date.today()) + '</request_id>'
  doc = lxml.etree.ElementTree(results)
  ins = lxml.etree.fromstring(req)
  ins.tail = "\n"
  dest = doc.xpath('/paiInv')[0]
  dest.insert(0,ins)
```

This gives me exactly what I need, except that if any columns in the csv are empty, I'll get empty xml tags, as would be expected. Since we're required to drop any empty tags, I've tried this code:

```
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(results)
  for element in root.xpath(".//*[not(node())]"):
    element.getparent().remove(element)
```

I receive an error saying "can only parse strings". I'm trying to understand why it would find anything other than strings, and how I should tweak the code that it will correctly drop empty tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to handle it: change your `for` loop at the end to:

```
for element in root.xpath('//*'):
    if element.text is None:
        elememt.getparent().remove(element)
```

The output should now have removed both `<addr_str2>` nodes which are empty.

Comment: Thanks @Jack Fleeting. I was also able to get the desired results by a simply converting the output to string first:  ```resultz =  (lxml.etree.tostring(results))```  But your solution seemed more elegant, so I used it instead. Thanks again.